# How Can I send custom logs to telemetry data

Tags: substrate-node-template, telemetry

I want to maintain log manager, especially for the custom logs.
I tried to integrate **graylog** server but available supporting crate for graylog does not have support for non-std so I am facing issue.
So can anyone suggest how can I maintain my substrate node logs.
Is it possible with **telemetry** to send custom logs from both runtime-context and ocw-context

Answer (score 1):

some wiki for Monitoring and Telemetry
:https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-node-management#monitoring-and-telemetry

for your commit QA:

1.the `Loki + promtail + Grafana` logging system may meet your needs.

Comment: I have tried to use different log levels and also the -ldebug flag from cli but, the logs are not visible in https://telemetry.polkadot.io/